# Is it possible to use template tags inside model field for displaying static images?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a huge report with some 50+ pages and there are several images and tables inside them. Is there any way I can put static tag inside textField which would be rendered in template, or I have to hardcode path inside model and use `report.chapter_one|safe` inside tempates?

report model looks like

```
chapter_one = models.TextField()
chapter_two = models.TextField()
chapter_three = models.TextField()
```

..etc

And there are some tables and images that go inside those chapters. So what's the best way to display them because in templates I call chapters like `report.chapter_one` and it displays a wall of text where I can't put image from inside template

Comment: Yes, you *render* the `.chapter_one`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rich text editor or markup language like Markdown or reStructuredText to handle images and tables within chapters. Save the content of each chapter as HTML or Markdown in a `TextField` and display it in the template using libraries like `Django-markdown` or `django-ckeditor` to manage images, tables, and other content. This lets you easily add images and tables while having more control over the formatting and presentation of the content.